# Defining custom events for TypeScript API

Tags: typescript

I am in the process of building the first iteration of an API. One of the things that we need is custom events for whoever is going to use our API. I am having trouble finding good documentation on how to build such things.

We have an interface for our API where I hope to define these custom events.

```
interface AddinApi{
    /**
    * Event fires when a document is opened.
    *
    * @param   {string}        The url of the of the document you are listening on.
    *   
    * @return  The url of the opened document
    */
    documentOpenedEvent(url: string): void;
}
```

I know that I am missing something here. Do I need to define some custom object that implements/extends some event class as the parameter?

The desired functionality of this event would be that the user can attach this event to a specific document, and when that document is opened, the event would fire.

This might be called in the following manner. This is more or less pseudo code.

```
var api : AddinApi;

// Define document object with some url / guid
var docGUID = "123456;

function onDocumentOpened(url: documentGuid){
   // do something now that the document has been opened
}

api.documentOpenedEvent = onDocumentOpened;

// Now this function fires off when the document is opened.
api.documentOpenedEvent(docGuid);
```

Comment: This isn't very clear. Can you post some examples of what the calling code would look like?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you would like to implement a simple [Observer pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern).

Then, code is quite simple:

Notifier:

```
class Notifier {
  private _subscribers : Array<ISubscriber>;

  constructor() {
    this._subscribers = new Array<ISubscriber>();
  }

  subscribe(o : ISubscriber) : void {
    this._subscribers.push(o);
  }

  myMethod() : void {
    // Trigger this method whenever you wish
    for (var i = 0; i < this._subscribers.length; i++) {
      // Notify each subscriber
      this._subscribers[i].onMyCustomEvent();
    }
  }
}
```

Subscriber interface:

```
interface ISubscriber {
  onMyCustomEvent() : void;
}
```

Finally, you can create your custom event args. You must only use it/them when notifying subscribers.